# cleaning strings before passing to jQuery ajax data parameter

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services

On using jQuery ajax on ASP.Net, we are required to pass the DATA through a string-ed json on the parameters needed. My only concern with this is with strings that has single & double quotes. I tried doing a replace on these and insert escape characters but unfortunately it just doesn't work.

help!

UPDATE

```
 var relativeName = $('#<%= txtRelativeName.ClientID %>').val().replace("'", "\'");

 $.ajax({ data: "{ relativeName: '" + relativeName + "'" });
```

Comment: How is this string-ed JSON generated? Post an example of your code.

Comment: can you be more specific on what did not work?

Comment: just updated my post. please see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about manually encoding parameters. Try like this:

```
var relativeName = $('#<%= txtRelativeName.ClientID %>').val();
$.ajax({ 
    data: JSON.stringify({ relativeName: relativeName }),
    ...
});
```

Comment: is JSON.stringify part of the jQuery core or the main framework itself? thanks man

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the .NET page needs data submitted as a JSON-encoded string inside a POST parameter. You can use [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to accomplish this:

```
var encoded = $.toJSON({ some: 'parameter' }); 
$.post(
 url: 'something.aspx',
 data: {
   jsonstr: encoded
 }
}
```